# Filtering IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> depending on several conditions on different sums

Tags: c#, linq

I've got a class like this :

```
public class CookingRecipe
{
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
    public int C { get; set; }

    public int Energy { get; set; }

    public CookingRecipe(int index, int a, int b, int c, int energie)
    {
        Index = index;
        A = a;
        B = b;
        C = c;
        Energy = energie;
    }
}
```

I've got 3 integer (MaxA, MaxB and MaxC) and a var IEnumerable<IEnumerable> like this, but I want to filter some IEnumerable that doesn't fit and with the max Energy :

[image: ![![Example]

What's the better way to do it by LINQ ?
I've edited because I've forgotten the max condition...

So I've got something like (thanks to magnus)

```
var result = MyList.Where(x => x.Sum(y => y.A) <= MaxA && x.Sum(y => y.B) <= MaxB && x.Sum(y => y.C) <= MaxC);
```

but how to add filter on the max energy ?

Comment: `q.Where(x => x.Sum(y => y.A) <= MaxA && x.Sum(y => y.B) <= MaxB)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Where` at the top level to filter on the sub-groups, and then use `Sum` on the sub-groups to compare against the Max* variables:

```
var ans = db.Where(crg => crg.Sum(cr => cr.A) <= MaxA &&
                          crg.Sum(cr => cr.B) <= MaxB &&
                          crg.Sum(cr => cr.C) <= MaxC &&
                          crg.Sum(cr => cr.Energy) <= MaxEnergie)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: The MaxA, MaxB and MaxC are known, but MaxEnergie need to be calculated...